# Building a k-d tree in Python

Tags: python, performance, tree, coordinate-system

To learn Python, I have implemented a function that creates a k-d tree from a list of 2-d Points. I would like to refer to this question where i asked about the [k-d tree in C](/questions/158486/implementation-of-k-d-tree/158506#158506). However, the Python code takes about 14 seconds for 1 million points. So my question is, are there optimizations that I can apply to my code to improve the performance?

```
  @staticmethod
  def build(bins, dimension=2, splittingAxis=0): 
    if not bins:
      return 
    splittingAxis = splittingAxis % dimension
    if splittingAxis == 0:
      bins.sort(key=lambda p: p.x)
    if splittingAxis == 1:
      bins.sort(key=lambda p: p.y)
    median = len(bins) // 2
    leftBin = build(bins[:median], splittingAxis + 1)
    rightBin = build(bins[median + 1:], splittingAxis + 1)
    return KdNode(bins[median], leftBin, rightBin, splittingAxis)
```

The KdNode is defined as follows :

```
 class KdNode(object):
    def __init__(self, currentBin=None, leftBin=None, rightBin=None, splittingAxis=0):
      self.currentBin = currentBin
      self.leftBin = leftBin
      self.rightBin = rightBin
      self.splittingAxis = splittingAxis
```

Comment: hi i understand, but it is really unimportant, i will remove KdSearch, it is just a wrapper

Comment: If the performance of the kd-tree is critical to your application, then using a pure-Python implementation is unlikely to work well. Instead, consider using [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).